# Xamarin Forms IOS Application Icon - File does not exist

Tags: ios, xamarin, appicon

I try to add an Icon to my xamarin app.. I am working on a Mac using Jetbrains Rider.

What I did:

I have created a set of Icons (different sizes) with Sketch. 
Then I opened the Info.Plist file from my Project .ios in XCode
In myApp.ios -> Assets.xcassets I created a new Set of Icons and with drag/drop I put in the pngs from Sketch.
Back in Rider the Info.Plist gets updated and the png files where added to the Project.

In my Info.Plist:

XSAppIconAssets -->
Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset

But if I build the project I get a list of error for each icon file

Assets.xcassets: The file "Icon-29@2x.png" for the image set "AppIcon" does not exist.

Do I miss something?

Comment: (edit) Ok re-reading the post I see that you added the icons through Xcode, those files might not be added to the Xamarin.Forms.iOS project file at all and that's why the error

Comment: The files are added to my project under Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset

Comment: ok, so try deleting the bin and obj directories from your `myApp.ios` project using the Finder.